# AJAX & Web Api Post Method - How does it work?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to write to my database using AJAX / Jquery and c#. Whenever I pass the parameter in to the C# code it shows as null. I am using the default template that visual studio generates when creating a controller class. Any help would be appreciated!

NOte: This is a rest service that I am trying to call. (A regular ASP website... not MVC. Also, the GET Rest api works perfectly.)

Jquery/AJAX:

```
var dataJSON = { "name": "test" }

$('#testPostMethod').bind("click", GeneralPost);
function GeneralPost() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../api/NewRecipe',
        data:JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

C#

```
    //If I remove the [FromBody] Tag then when I click the button this method is never called.
    public void Post([FromBody]string name)

    {

    }
```

EDIT:

I have adjusted my code slightly but am still encountering the same issue. To recap, It is loading the POST method, but it is passing in null.

C#

```
 public class RecipeInformation
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

    }

        public void Post(RecipeInformation information)

        {

        }
```

AJAX:

```
    var dataJSON = { information: { name: "test" } };

    $('#testPostMethod').bind("click", GeneralPost);
    console.log(dataJSON);
    function GeneralPost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../api/NewRecipe',
            data: dataJSON,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is `Post(string name)` part of an MVC application, a web service, or what?

Comment: Sorry, this is ASP - a Rest service. The GET works perfectly.

Comment: @Yecats where is your [WebMethod] attribute and static keyword to make the method available?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For simple type,  on server side:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string name)
{
}
```

on the client side, you just define if you want to send in json format:

```
    var dataJSON = "test";

    $('#testPostMethod').bind("click", GeneralPost);
    function GeneralPost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/NewRecipe',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

If you want to make it work in complex type, from server side you should define:

```
public class RecipeInformation
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(RecipeInformation information)
    {
    }
}
```

And from client side:

```
    var dataJSON = { name: "test" };

    $('#testPostMethod').bind("click", GeneralPost);
    function GeneralPost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/NewRecipe',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ah! Finally a solution that works! I tested out the complex type and it works perfectly. :)

Comment: How would I add more parameters to my complex data? This JSON doesn't work beyond name -             var dataJSON = { name: "test", category: "1",prepTime:"60", cookTime:"40",standTime:"32", imgPath:"something.jpg",status:"1" };

Comment: In json, you value can be another json object (ex: `{ name: "test", category: "1", time:{prepTime:"60", cookTime:"40"},standTime:"32", imgPath:"something.jpg",status:"1" }`

Comment: Using webapi 2.0, I copy pasted the the first example from your answer and keep getting "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405"

Comment: Excellent solution! I was looking for the reason why my post was not working. You just gave the perfect answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't see NewRecipe method

Comment: Just want to add my thanks! for this solution. It worked great for me.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you are using ASP.NET WebAPI and it bind all simple types (int, bool, string, etc) from URL and all complex types from body. When you marked name with `FromBody` attribute then it bind it from request body instead of url mapping.

You can read more about ASP.NET WebAPI routing and parameter binding here:

- [On www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)
- [On www.west-wind.com](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/21/ASPNET-Web-API-and-Simple-Value-Parameters-from-POSTed-data)
- and on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)

Comment: I only used frombody because the template generated it as such. I have updated my code above to reflect how I would really like to pass the information in.

Comment: This was an extremely good read though, thanks for sending it!

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing something like this and use the jquery param method

```
    var postData = {
        name : 'name'
    }

    $('#testPostMethod').bind("click", GeneralPost);
    function GeneralPost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../api/NewRecipe',
            data: $.param(postData,true),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this fixed the issue. I am still encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a piece you're missing is the data contract attributes
If you make a your class like:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class RecipeInformation
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

These attributes are found in System.Runtime.Serialization, and the Json parser (Json.NET) uses them to (help) deserialize the model.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Binding in API controllers is a little on the strange side.  I believe:

```
public void Post([FromBody]RecipeInformation information)
```

with

```
var dataJSON = { name: "test" };
```

should work, and will definitely work if you just pass it as form data.

Comment: I have tried that (and just tried it again). This doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with help from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1#sending_form_data_via_ajax)
Use JS code as mentioned

```
$.post('api/updates/simple', { "": $('#status1').val() });
```

What I missed was adding empty property name, so what OP needs to do is`{"":data:JSON.stringify(dataJSON)},` instead of `data:JSON.stringify(dataJSON),`

Answer (score 0):

$("#updateuser").click(function ()
        {

```
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var dataJSON = $("#username").val();

        alert("" + dataJSON);

        $.ajax({


            url: 'http://localhost:44700/api/Home/' + id,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    $("<li>" + val + "</li>").appendTo($("#names"));
                })
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error in Operation');
            }

            })

    })
```