# ASP MVC ajax POST string controller variable is null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Jquery and controller code are like following

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/api/ComicApi",
         datatype: "text",
         data: encoded, //encoded is a MIME64 string    
         type: "POST",
         error: function (request, status, error) {
                  alert('error');
                },
         success: function (data) {

                }
});
```

> ComicApiController.cs

```
 // POST api/<controller>
 [HttpPost] // tried with [HttpPost] and without
 public void Post([FromBody]string data)
 {
   // I hit my breakpoint, but data is ALWAYS null
 }
```

Comment: please check this post :https://stackoverflow.com/a/15700385/1875256

Comment: why dont you use /api/ComicApi/Post url

Comment: did answer work?

Comment: @hasan power was out -- I won't be able to test it for a few days, I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

can you try this with `[HttpPost]`

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url:  "/api/ComicApi",
       data: JSON.stringify(encoded),
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: 'json'
       error: function (request, status, error) {
                 alert('error');
              },
       success: function (data) {
                 console.log("success");
              }
});
```